# Is there a purpose to the goodberry spell allowing spell resistance?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, spell-resistance

Do any of the published campaign settings have magic-resistant berries or something?

Comment: Alternatively, there might be published campaigns with sentient berries who don't want to be turned into goodberries...

Comment: You should accord your title and your question, the first specify goodberry while the last is about any berries. You should also be more precise about what you are searching for. Does the berry grant the eater magic-resistance, does the berry itself resist fire? Anything else?

Comment: The only thing I could see, and I don't know if it works (will make an answer if this is confirmed) a Monk with Diamond Soul, polymorphed into a berry, might keep his spell Resistance, I've made so many research, I guess that's all I could find... I found some plant monsters with berries but goodberry states the fruits must had been picked up (freshly picked) so you can't cast it while it's on the creature, haven't found any berry ennemies xD

Comment: This remains a thing even in the premium edition *Player's Handbook* (2012) that includes stealth errata. (In *2nd Edition* the *goodberry* spell was reversible (*badberry*?) so it could deal damage therefore making magic resistance against its effect a thing, but *3.5* both made the *goodberry* spell not reversible and changed how magic resistance (now spell resistance) works.)

Comment: @Zoma The title *is* the question. While in most cases a question repeats the question's title in its body, there's no requirement that I'm aware of that it must. Thus these aren't disparate questions but one question: The one in the title, then the question wonders if that reason is, like, *Everyone knows berry bushes are sentient in Greyhawk!* or whatever. It's a perfectly cromulent question, despite its structure being nonstandard (for this stack, anyway).

Comment: @HeyICanChan Thank you, as I'm not a native English speaker plus being more used to "traditional" question format I had trouble making sense here. It comforts me in the fact that only one line in the question part is pretty poor.

Answer (score 1):

*The spell resistance, in this case, is not to "turn" the berries, but for creature who consumes them.*

It allows SR for the off-chance you try to give one to an undead (who would be healed by the berry: takes 1 damage) - this is the only reason I could think of, and it depends on your DM ruling that the goodberry is Positive Energy.

Comment: Unfortunately, even then, spell resistance against this spell doesn't work that way: "If your spell is being resisted by a creature [i.e. target] with spell resistance [like the hypothetical berries rather than the eater of said berries], you must make a caster level check…" (*PH* 177).